# How to get the Facebook Update Status feeds for logged in user?

Tags: c#, .net

How to get the updatestatus of a loggedin user in facebook?
I am develooping a wpf application which is integrated with facebook.
I want to show the status updates of the user.
What is the query to fetch the Update Status.
Pleas let me know.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using the facebook api?
look at this: [Facebook API using](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=6129852276&topic=3773)